# Facebook Comments iframe cutting off reply menu

Tags: facebook

Reply menu is cutting off at the bottom when there are multiple Facebook accounts to reply as. Facebook's iFrame does not appear to resize itself. Is there a solution to this?

[image: screen recording]

Answer (score 0):

There was `overflow:hidden` applied to the container containing the plugin. Removing it fixed the issue.